# $x^2$ in a different form?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it known that $x^2=$ the sum of all of the numbers underneath it doubled, plus $x$?

Thought of it, thinking about pyramid push ups so $3^2= 2(1)+2(2)+3$,

$5^2= 2(1)+2(2)+2(3)+2(4)+5$

Answer (score 2):

Draw dots formed an $n\times n$ square, and split it to $3$ parts: one diagonal, dots below it, and dots above it.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the following
$$n^2 \overset{?}{=} 2(1 + 2 + \cdots + (n-1)) + n.$$

You have verified it for $n=3$. (You can check $n=2$ as well.)

For a proof by induction, you need to prove the inductive step.
Specifically, if the above holds with $n=k$, can you prove it holds with $n=k+1$?

> $$(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1 = (2(1+\cdots+(k-1)) + k) + 2k + 1 = 2(1+\cdots+k) + (k+1) $$

Comment: What I meant, was has it already been thought of? Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: There are lots of this kind of identities, most of them could be found in the e exercise section, for e.g. induction..

Comment: Thank you. Very much appreciated.